# CakePHP passing arguments in Controller::redirect

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, cakephp-2.0

In controller actions to make redirect I use this:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'tools', 'action' => 'index'));
```

or this

```
$this->redirect('/tools/index');
```

And when I pass data with redirect I use this:

```
$this->redirect('tools/index/?myArgument=12');
```

But I couldn't find how to pass "myargument" by "this-redirect-array" notation.
I don't want to use this because some routing issues:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'tools', 'action' => 'index', "myArgument"));
```

I need something like this:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'tools', 'action' => 'index', "?myArgument=12"));
```

Comment: As Jleagle demonstrates, it _is_ possible to use the array notion to create standard RFC 3986 query strings, but it's generally not a good idea. Is there a particular reason you don't want to use Cake's friendly URL routing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cake does indeed support query arguments using the question mark, like this:

```
$this->redirect(array(
    'controller' => 'tools', 'action' => 'index', '?' => array(
        'myArgument' => 12
    )
));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#reverse-routing

But it would be better to just do, like des said:

```
$this->redirect(array(
    'controller' => 'tools', 'action' => 'index', 'myArgument' => 12
));
```

Comment: Correct, I didn't knew `'?'` can be used to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'tools', 'action' => 'index', 'myArgument' => 12));
```

Take a look at [CakePHP Cookbook - Controller::redirect](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3aredirect)

[Accessing request parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-request-parameters):

```
$this->request['myArgument'];
$this->request->myArgument;
$this->request->params['myArgument'];
```

Comment: Well, that solution will create this: "**tools/index/myArgument:12**"  But I need this: "**tools/index/?myArgument=12**"

Comment: any reason why? You can access that parameter using `$this->params['named']`. Depending on how you pass the extra params depends on the URL that is output.  [More in the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/963/The-Parameters-Attribute-params)

Comment: @trante I've edited my answer to show you how this parameter can be accessed. I see no reason to mix `CakePHP` routes with classic query string. Is there any specific reason for this? @Ross good comment, but question is for `CakePHP2` ;)

Comment: @des Because I didn't want to change too much routing code for just one case :) :)

Comment: @trante simple you can use ?
`$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'tools', 'action' => 'index', '?' => array('variableName' => 'variableValue')));`
and then in action index you can use `$variableValue = $this->request->query('variableName');`

Answer (score 0):

Using this to redirect:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'tools', 'action' => 'index', 'myArgument' => 12));
```

And Router::connectNamed() to router.php to change separator from ":" to "=":

```
Router::connectNamed(
    array('myArgument' => array('action' => 'index', 'controller' => 'tools')), array('default' => false, 'greedy' => false, 'separator' => '=')
```

);