# Cakephp redirect with get variable

Tags: cakephp

I am refreshing a page in my controller with `return $this->redirect($this->request->here);`
Which works great.

But I want to add a GET variable to the refresh. Does anyone know how to do this?

It is not possible to use the Cakephp redirect function with controller and action because of the routing I am using. So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814777/cake-php-redirect-with-parameters-in-url) is not going to work for me

Comment: It was many times:   
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814777/cake-php-redirect-with-parameters-in-url   
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177154/cakephp-passing-arguments-in-controllerredirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return $this->redirect($this->request->here . '?key=val');
```